# Running .war files with Jetty

Tags: java, heroku, jetty, war

I'm struggling with creating the most basic of examples of running a Jetty application and launching a .war package at the same time. Everything I find just says to put the .war in "$JETTY_HOME/webapps", but I'm not sure how to verify what "$JETTY_HOME" is. I'm trying to extend the simple heroku default application found at `https://github.com/heroku/java-getting-started.git`. My directory structure:

```
src/
-- main/
---- java/
------ Main.java
target/
-- (lots of stuff in here)
pom.xml
Procfile
webapps/
-- workbench.war
```

I run my application with `java -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Main`.

`Main.java` is identical to: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heroku/java-getting-started/master/src/main/java/Main.java.

How can I get this application to run .war files? Whenever I visit `localhost:5000/workbench` I just see "Hello World" where I should be seeing the Workbench application contained in `workbench.war`.

Comment: That example doesn't use a war file at all, it uses direct Servlet definitions.

Comment: I want to extend this "example" so it can do both.

Comment: The "context" around a webapp means you need to have everything inside of that context, or it will be different contexts.  keep that in mind when you decide what you want to do.  It is difficult (but not impossible) to mix a auto-built war context with its auto-loading of descriptors and some manual servlets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your are trying to run jetty embeded in your application, and want it to serve a war file. Check this link
http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedded-examples.html#embedded-one-webapp

Answer (score 1):

If its just a single war, do this.

```java
package org.eclipse.jetty.demo;

import org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.TagLibConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration;

public class EmbedMe
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        int port = 8080;
        Server server = new Server(port);

        String warpath = "webapps/workbench.war";

        WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
        context.setResourceBase(warpath);
        context.setConfigurations(new Configuration[]
        { 
            new AnnotationConfiguration(), 
            new WebInfConfiguration(), 
            new WebXmlConfiguration(), 
            new MetaInfConfiguration(), 
            new FragmentConfiguration(),
            new EnvConfiguration(), 
            new PlusConfiguration(), 
            new JettyWebXmlConfiguration() 
        });

        context.setContextPath("/");
        context.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
        server.setHandler(context);
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising - will this allow me to run the war and listen for other routes?